# Is it possible to configure c-lightning cookie based auth to bitcoind as opposed to rpcuser/rpcpassword?

Tags: json-rpc, core-lightning, authentication

Is it possible to configure c-lightning cookie based authentication to bitcoind as opposed to rpcuser/rpcpassword?

Does `lightning.conf` read the rpcuser/rpcpassword from `bitcoin.conf`?

This question was asked by Kalle Rosenbaum on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/kallerosenbaum/status/1432051566387908612?s=20).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to configure c-lightning cookie based authentication to bitcoind as opposed to rpcuser/rpcpassword?

Yes it works with `.cookie` now. It is automatic, it is the positive side effect of c-lightning invoking bitcoin-cli to communicate with bitcoind instead of handling RPC and authentication itself.

> Does `lightning.conf` read the rpcuser/rpcpassword from `bitcoin.conf`?

No.

This was answered by various individuals on Twitter.